# How can I improve my SQL code for correct results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, I am not sure what is the best way to this problem. But let me give you an example. What I am trying to achieve here is get the P2 value which is equal to carry when trying to sum P2 values in the descending order.. 10 to 1.

I have a huge table:

```
Category_Id Brand_Id Carry P2_0  P2_1  P2_3 ... P2_10
9           54       59    12    3     17       .
7           6        102   4     0     3        .
9           71       54    20    1     0        .
9           75       98    34    4     0        .
7           10       140   59    5     4        .
```

This is main logic of my code:

```
SELECT CategoryCode,Brand_Id, (CASE
    WHEN P2_10 > =  Carry Then 'Error' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 > =  Carry Then '10' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8  > =  Carry Then '9' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7  >=  Carry Then '8' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6  >=  Carry Then '7'
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 > =  Carry Then '6' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 + P2_4 > =  Carry Then '5'
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 + P2_4 + P2_3 > =  Carry Then '4' 
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 + P2_4 + P2_3 + P2_2 > =  Carry Then '3'
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 + P2_4 + P2_3 + P2_2 + P2_1 > =  Carry Then '2'
    WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 + P2_6 + P2_5 + P2_4 + P2_3 + P2_2 + P2_1 + P2_0 > =  Carry Then '1'
    ELSE NULL END) As Threshold  from BQ_15
```

Now the issue here is say for a brand_id 6 if the carry is 106 then

```
 P2_10(50) + P2_9(50) + P2_8(3) + P2_7(3) = Carry (106) gives the right result 

 but if  P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 > Carry it has to go back to previous result, if in the previous result the new P2 was '0' it has to back further. 

 so if P2_10(50) + P2_9(50) + P2_8(2) + P2_7(0) + P2_6(30) > Carry (106) then it should skip P2_7 (because it is zero) and go to P2_8 (desired result) but for my code it goes to P2_7.
```

I know I haven't included anything that skips '0' that is where my entire issue lies is how do I iterate in SQL that my code will work for both the cases and get the desired result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you need to iterate? Am I missing something here?

Comment: To check if the P2 value is zero if it is zero then go back till the last P2 value is not zero. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: if both "P2_10(50) + P2_9(50) + P2_8(2) + P2_7(0)" and "P2_10(50) + P2_9(50) + P2_8(2)" are equal to carry (because P2_7 is 0) then your case statement will match to 9 since "WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 =  Carry Then '9' " condition is satisfied first. Which as far as I understand is the result you wanted. Am I wrong? You want your result to be 8 or 9 for this scenario?

Comment: if you see my last snippet the first sum was equal to carry which is fine.. but the 3rd sum is greater than carry(106) so technically it should go back to P2_8 (what I want) and not P2_7( what I get)

Comment: Your first 5 condition checks whether your sum is equal to carry or not whereas the rest of your condition checks whether your sum is equal or greater than your carry.

If this condition "WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 =  Carry Then '9' " is satisfied first your query wont check other conditions. So you may need to change the first five checks to >= also maybe?

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot to add greater than here in the question, but the issue is still the same. It is my first time posting a question.

Comment: This smells like a need for  `UNPIVOT` to turn columns into rows here...

Comment: Yes I did that too but I wasn't sure how I would tell my code to sum up one column and give the P2 value from parallel column. if that makes any sense.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yea unpivot would be a better way to implement it definitely. Also as far I see, there is also a mistake in the logic above :
The condition for being greater than or equal to carry is satisfied only in the 5th case(P2_10(50) + P2_9(50) + P2_8(2) + P2_7(0) + P2_6(30) >= Carry (106) ). So not sure why he wants it to match 3rd case.

Comment: Are these sums always based on a sequence?  You could unpivot the data then use windowed summation functions with a group by.  (sounds complex but it would look pretty clean once written)

Comment: @hchaznedaroglu Esentially I am calculating a threshold value here so if it is greater it has to go back to the previous value, that was the my question  in the first place is how do I tell my code to go previous value.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Yes it in always in a sequence, I just dint know how to find a threshold value from column A if I am summing numbers in column 'B' ? this is when I unpivot the data. can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cross apply to make row scope calculations. I took 4 p2_xx columns, extend it as needed.

```
from (
     -- sample data
     values (9,54,106,  50,50,2,0,30)     
     ) hugeTable (Category_Id, Brand_Id, Carry, P2_10, P2_9, P2_8, P2_7, P2_6) 
cross apply (
    select Threshold = min(p2n)
    from (
        select p2n,
             s = sum(p2val) over(order by p2n desc)
        from (
             values
             (10, P2_10), (9, P2_9), (8, P2_8), (7, P2_7), (6, P2_6) 
        ) t(p2n, p2val)
        where p2val>0
    ) t
    where s <= Carry
) t
```

I use sum() over(), if you are on 2008 or earlier version then

```
from (
     -- sample data
     values (9,54,106,  50,50,2,0,30)     
     ) hugeTable (Category_Id, Brand_Id, Carry, P2_10, P2_9, P2_8, P2_7, P2_6) 
cross apply (
    select Threshold = min(p2n)
    from (
        select p2n,
             s = (select sum(p2val)
                 from (
                      values
                      (10, P2_10), (9, P2_9), (8, P2_8), (7, P2_7), (6, P2_6)  
                 ) t2(p2n, p2val)
                 where t2.p2n>=t.p2n )
        from (
             values
             (10, P2_10), (9, P2_9), (8, P2_8), (7, P2_7), (6, P2_6)  
        ) t(p2n, p2val)
        where p2val>0
    ) t
    where s <= Carry
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll have any issues with the previous answer using `cross appy`. If you do have complications or if you wanted to stick with your original case expression it isn't too difficult to find an expression that works--it's just a little messy. Here's what one of the cases could look like:

```
WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 >= Carry
THEN coalesce(
    nullif(sgn(P2_8)  *  8, 0),
    nullif(sgn(P2_9)  *  9, 0),
    nullif(sgn(P2_10) * 10, 0),
    -1
)
```

And actually that's unnecessarily complicated when you really just need to nest `case` expressions. Perhaps that's something you didn't realize was possible:

```
WHEN P2_10 + P2_9 + P2_8 + P2_7 >= Carry
THEN case when P2_8 > 0 then 8 when P2_9 > 0 then 9 when P2_10 > 0 then 10 else -1 end
```

Do you ever have sequences that start out with all zeroes that then jump over the carry threshhold: `(0, 0, 0, 200)`? And what about sums that never exceed the carry? I don't believe the other answer covers that scenario.

Comment: I tired the nested  'case' expression and it worked, I never gave it a try before because of the 10 cases limit I thought it had. Thanks fam !

Comment: I think that's the nesting limit but not the maximum number of cases. Glad it worked.